# Apply current category's filter to productCollection

Tags: php, magento

I know that I can get product collection

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');` .

How can I filter this product collection with categoryId and its filter ?

The filters I'm talking about are filters when we click on layered navigation sidebar ( attribute options ..) .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'));` on your collection (check if you have a current_cateogry prior to this)

Comment: how about current_category's filter ? The one you click on layered navigation bar

Comment: Like you said, in standard magento, this behavior exists already via the catagory-filter. What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: ah ha, so we get our filter through current_category as well ? We don't need any other things like filters ?

Comment: If you activate the "category" filter, when you are in a category with layered navigation, the category-filter will display all the subcategories of your current-category. If you click a sub-category you virtually go into this category by filtering the product-list on the clicked category (though, you're still in the original category)